# Updating tableadapter throws error Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, debugging, exception, formatting, tableadapter

When I call

```
TA.Update(row)
```

I receive the following error, but I have no idea how to debug it. Is there a way to determine which exact field is causing the issue?

Server Error in '/' Application.

Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

Line 7381:         Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")>  _
Line 7382:        Public Overloads Overridable Function Update(ByVal dataRow As Global.System.Data.DataRow) As Integer
Line 7383:            Return Me.Adapter.Update(New Global.System.Data.DataRow() {dataRow})
Line 7384:        End Function
Line 7385:

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aebf90fc\865092c3\App_Code.6h2d5goz.23.vb    Line: 7383

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14365689
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +305
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +859
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming) +1809

[FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.]
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount) +2290668
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount) +75
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping) +3479
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows) +319
   adsTableAdapters.adsTableAdapter.Update(DataRow dataRow) in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aebf90fc\865092c3\App_Code.6h2d5goz.23.vb:7383
   editad.lbSaveLocation_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dropbox\inetpub\zz\editad.aspx.vb:765
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +153
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Tried adding check on errors like so, but no errors occur:

```
Try
        If TA.Update(row) = 1 Then

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim arr As Array = row.Table.GetErrors()
        'arr.length=1 here
        If arr.Length > 0 Then
            lblStatus.Text = row.Table.GetErrors(0).ToString
'the value of row.Table.GetErrors(0).ToString is "ads+adsRow"
        End If            
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

[This exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can have many reasons(f.e. `int.Parse("abc")`).

You can execute that line in a [**quick-watch-window**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx) of the debugger in visual studio. Then you can retrieve the `rows` which contains all row errors via [`DataTable.GetErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.geterrors.aspx):

```
row.Table.GetErrors()
```

Then you're able to inspect these rows. Have a look at the [`DataRow.RowError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowerror.aspx) property. There you'll find the detailed error and column which causes the exception.

All in the quick watch window, otherwise you cannot debug that exception.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But before I could do that I need to be able to generally debug, which is not working at this moment. First I fix that and then I look again into this. If you feel like doing so, have a look at my other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406936/asp-net-debugging-redirects-to-invalid-url

Comment: be particularly suspicious of any DateTime fields that allow nulls. the command parameter for that field may have a problem if its passed a null, and as a datetime is passed from .net to sql, it does so as a string, and then gets recast by the sql server.

Comment: @FrankThomas: the weird thing is that before I do the update, I retrieve the record to be updated and load that in a row of the datatable. So I would guess if there was some constraint on any column, the error would already be thrown the moment I retrieve the record right? My update command is btw autogenerated and to be sure I checked whether any date column had AllowDbNull set to true, but none of them have...

Comment: @Floran: Have you checked the `RowEror` property?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I updated my post with your suggestion, but I get no errors there...

Comment: @Floran: Please read my answer again. You need to use the quick watch window.  You can not get the errors from code and row.Table.GetErrors will be available after TA.Update(row) not before.  Instead of the debugger window you could also try to put it in your Catch/block instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter since I have some problems with regular debugging I decided to try it via your suggestion in Try Catch, see my update

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I debugged it by setting all columns of the table adapter manually so I knew all values where correctly formatted.
The problem still occurred. In SQL Profiler I saw no update commands passing, so nothing was ever passed to the DB.
Solution: in the autogenerated update command of the table adapter the update parameter was called @Original_id. I renamed to @id and it worked :S