# ASP.NET debugging redirects to invalid url

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to debug my application, but I can't find the correct URL to do so.

After I click F5 (start debugging) in Visual Studio 2010 I see the following in the system tray notification window:

```
ASP.NET Development Server  
http://localhost:1392/zz
```

But in the Chrome browser address that is opened the URL is:

```
http://www.localhost/zz/editad.aspx
```

and I see a notification: 
Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.localhost

If I change the address manually to

```
http://localhost:1392/zz
```

it redirects back again to

```
http://www.localhost/zz/editad.aspx again
```

So I can't seem to debug my website.

I have hostsman running with the following URL's:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.0.10    www.zorgbeurs.nl
192.168.0.10    zorgbeurs.nl
```

Not sure if it matters but in my web.config I have.
As rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="edit ad">?/?
<match url="^account/edit-ad/([0-9]+)?/??(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="editad.aspx?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And to prevent unauthorized access:

```
<location path="editad.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

What can I do to be able to debug?

Comment: search for the string `editad` in your solution?

Comment: I did, only occurrences are in web.config, I updated my post with that info. I also tested if for default.aspx, which has no weird things going on and the same happens, but only with "default.aspx", instead of "editad.aspx"

Comment: trying removing these references to `editid` (temporarily) and see what happens? Is your server redirecting you to that page? (use your web debugger to see whats happening behind the scenes)

Comment: how it behaves on other browsers?

Comment: I removed all references, but once I press F5 in VS while I'm on editad.aspx, I'm stilling seeing the same behavior. What webdebugger do you talk about which allows me to see what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: @JigarPandya behavior in other browsers is the same